# How to delete all the rows present in SharePoint excel sheet table using python?

Tags: python, excel, for-loop, sharepoint-online, azure-logic-apps

Q1.how to integrate deleting all rows for example (25 columns and 1500 rows) in the table, where excel sheet located in Sharepoint using python code?

Q2.May I know the approx time consumption of executing For-loop for 1500 items in python?

Q3.Deleting rows possible using the azure logic app but time-consuming process.

each trigger time =  8/7/6 mins

Number of row deletion limit = 256 rows

Do we have any logic to delete all the rows in one trigger? the table remains same only all the rows get deleted in azure logic app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Microsoft graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/tablerow-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0) to delete rows in your python code:

```
POST /workbook/tables/{id|name}/rows/{index}/delete
POST /workbook/worksheets/{id|name}/tables/{id|name}/rows/{index}/delete
```

You need to get the access token in your python code first, and request the graph api with access token in its header.